# How to show all the numbers in funnel plot in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I was doing some funnel plot using plotly, however, when I wanted to show the texts outside the box there is no text in left side and there is text in only right side.

## setup

```py
from plotly import graph_objects as go


stages = ["Homepage visit", "Search page visit",
           "Payment Page", "Payment Confirmation"]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Desktop',
    y = stages,
    x = [30100, 27090,  2860,   150],
    textposition = "outside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous"))

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Mobile',
    orientation = "h",
    y = stages,
    x = [15100, 12080,  2718,   302],
    textposition = "outside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous"))

fig.show()
```

## output

[image]

## required

I want to see all the numbers. I tried both 'inside' and 'outside' but I was unable to see ALL the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not it, but it is something in this path, try exploring `constraintext` and text formatting:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go


stages = ["Homepage visit", "Search page visit",
           "Payment Page", "Payment Confirmation"]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Desktop',
    y = stages,
    x = [30100, 27090,  2860,   150],
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous"
    , constraintext='outside'

    ,textfont=dict(
        family="sans serif",
        size=14,
        color="black"
    )

)


             )

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Mobile',
    orientation = "h",
    y = stages,
    x = [15100, 12080,  2718,   302],
    textposition = "auto",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous"))

fig.show()
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I was wondering if you know how it were possible to change the size of each 'panel' in the funnel chart. Thanks for any help.